# Why was this question given a 5e tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, specific-question

I was browsing the [play-by-post] tag and found this question:

[How can a player in a PbP D&D 5e game ensure the health and fun of that game?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53270/23064)

However, it was tagged for Dnd 5e but reading the question, it seems pretty system-agnostic. Perhaps there were deleted comments but I don't see why it would need the DnD 5e tag with how this is worded.

Sidenote: I plan to open a bounty on it.

Comment: [This question and its answers](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3010/4398) will provide useful background on the topic.

Comment: If the answers you're getting aren't addressing your concern, please edit your question to make it more clear *why* you think it would be advantageous (and to whom) to have the tag changed. You may be assuming we understand an implied reason that seems obvious to you but that we're missing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The point of the Stack Exchange is to provide actionable suggestions for resolving the specific challenges querents face, in a system that sorts itself for easy reference so we become an organised collection of solutions to problems.

This is why **we don't change someone else's question to artificially broaden its scope**: not only is it horribly pretentious to think we understand a challenge better than the person who has it, but the generalisation usually reduces the value of the contribution to the Stack.

Years of experience have shown that answers to specific questions are often also useful to people with similar but not identical situations. The better an answer explains the reasoning behind its specific solution, the more broadly its principles can be applied.

That same experience repeatedly demonstrates that answers to artificially broadened questions are rarely actionably useful to the person asking the question because they can't address the details of the situation. They can't provide solutions to the specific challenge being faced, they can only provide broad principles that may or may not actually be helpful to the querent. Those situations often wind up with every answer getting a comment from the querent saying "Okay, but in my situation [edge case or exception which renders answer useless]."

Answer (score 5):

## Because the querent put it there.

If you think the question can be edited to be generic without changing the essence of the question, suggest the edit, and remove the tag.  As it stands, there is nothing wrong with keeping it tagged for 5E, and it MIGHT be relevant.

Comment: Ah, rats. I missed this. All I saw was @doppelgreener edit the title and some of the body and automatically assumed he edited the tags as well. Thanks I'll try to think this through and see if the tag can be removed after all.

Comment: @daze413 Since its not at risk of being closed (as of right now), err on the side of leaving it be, if in doubt

Comment: @daze413 You may also be [underestimating the scope of the RPG landscape](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1475/4398). The one answer given for that question so far would be nigh meaningless in several of the systems I use regularly, for example, and free-form PbP would need totally different answers again.

Comment: @BESW perhaps a less-narrow tag would be appropriate? Instead of [dnd-5e] it can be [dungeons-and-dragons]?

Comment: We do not practice artificial scope widening here - people should ask about their specific problem.  We went through a time earlier in the sites history where that got hashed out (probably there's old metas on it). We learned over time it's a bad practice and scope should only be wide in specific and rare cases where the queer the really does have the same issue with multiple games and the answers aren't going to vary by game.